# SQL query MATCH not working with selected columns

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, match

i have this query:

```
SELECT (
  *)
   ,
  MATCH(table1.tags,table1.title,table1.description) AGAINST ('".$keywords."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS ideas_score 
  FROM table1  JOIN table2 ON table1.id_user = table2.id  HAVING ideas_score > 0 
  ORDER BY ideas_score DESC;
```

why does if i do this it doesn't works?

```
SELECT (
   table1.description,
 table1.title,
   table1.id,
   table1.id_user,
   table1.tags,
   table1.insert_datetime,
   table2.fb_id,
   table2.fb_aliasname,
   table2.firstname,
   table2.lastname)
   ,
  MATCH(table1.tags,table1.title,table1.description) AGAINST ('".$keywords."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS ideas_score 
  FROM table1  JOIN table2 ON table1.id_user = table2.id  HAVING ideas_score > 0 
  ORDER BY ideas_score DESC;
```

i always receive this error:

```
Error Number: 1241

Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OMG sorry i just noticed that SELECT do not need `()`